# Java JSON Select Custom Attribute Dynamically

Tags: java, json

I have a class

```
public class Item {
    private String atr1;
    private String atr2;
    private String atr3;
    private String atr4;
}
```

Then I put a list of items in a JSONObject

```
Item item1 = new Item();
Item item2 = new Item();
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
items.add(item1);
items.add(item2);

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("items", items);
```

I need to get result like this

```
items:[
    {
    "atr1":"somevalue",
    "atr2":"somevalue",
    "atr3":"somevalue",
    "atr4":"somevalue"
    },

    {
    "atr1":"somevalue",
    "atr2":"somevalue",
    "atr4":"somevalue"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the first item has 4 attributes and the second has 3 attributes. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Specify your question. Is atr3 null?

For what I understood, try using `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` with constraint that suit your needs (I recommend using Jackson for Java integration with JSON objects)

Comment: No. It's not null, but I don't want to include atr3 in the first item.

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this, is either creating `@JsonCreator` methods which will be responsible for creating a JSON (there, you can exclude some fields depending on your needs), or manipulate your values, by temporary setting them e.x. to null, and using `@JsonInclude`